# On an isomorphism between $p$-adic power series and an inverse limit

Tags: power-series, p-adic-numbers, iwasawa-theory

Let $K$ be an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, let $O$ be the ring of integers of $K$, and let $P$ be the maximal ideal of $O$.

If $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, there is the well-known algebraic isomorphism

$$O[[X]]\cong\varprojlim O[X]/((1+X)^{p^n}-1).$$

A proof of this fact can be found, for example, in Lang's "Cyclotomic fields", in Washington's "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields", and in Neukirch et al's "Cohomology of number fields". In all of this proofs, at some point one needs a generator of the maximal ideal $M$, that is, a uniformizer element of $K$. Hence, *a priori*, this proofs do not work if we let $K$ to be a non discretely valued extension.

Now, in page 96 of Lang's "Cyclotomic fields I and II", he claims (and uses) that this isomorphism is true when one let $K=\mathbb{C}_p$, the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. My question is: **where can I find a proof of this?**, or, **why is this obviously true?**, since he only proves this isomorphism for $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Note: Since I do not know too much about (the foundations of) Iwasawa theory, I do not know if this is an elementary question. If it is, please let me know and I will ask it in MSE.

Comment: Why shouldn't the proof work if $O/M$ is infinite?  Any discretely valued field has a uniformiser; this is just another name for an element of least positive valuation.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the remark. It was a stupidity of mine. I had a lapsus and confused two different things. I will edit the question.

Comment: @LSpice Note that $\mathbb{C}_p$ is not discretely-valued.

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo, indeed.  I did not mean to suggest that the issue did not arise for $\mathbb C_p$, only that it did not come (as the post originally suggested) from the infinitude of $O/M$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is unique division with remainder by a monic polynomial in $O[X]$, where $O$ is any commutative ring. When $O$ is a $p$-adically complete ring, the Weierstrass division theorem tells us there is unique division with remainder by a polynomial in $O[[X]]$ that is *distinguished*: monic with lower degree coefficients in the maximal ideal of $O$.  Therefore, since $(1+X)^{p^n}-1$ is both monic and distinguished when $O$ is $p$-adically complete (as its non-leading coefficients are all divisible by $p$), the natural composite mapping $O[X] \rightarrow O[[X]] \rightarrow O[[X]]/((1+X)^{p^n}-1)$ is surjective with kernel the ideal $((1+X)^{p^n}-1)$ in $O[X]$, so we have a natural ring isomorphism
$$
O[X]/((1+X)^{p^n}-1) \cong O[[X]]/((1+X)^{p^n}-1).
$$
This is compatible with the inverse system built on both sides from the ideals $((1+X)^{p^n}-1)$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, so we get an isomorphism of inverse limits 
$$
\varprojlim O[X]/((1+X)^{p^n}-1) \cong \varprojlim O[[X]]/((1+X)^{p^n}-1).
$$
The ring $O[[X]]$ is complete with respect to the $(p,X)$-adic topology 
and let's show $(1+X)^{p^n}-1 \subset (p,X)^n$. The ideal is $(p^n,p^{n-1}X,\ldots,pX^{n-1},X^n)$, the polynomial is $\sum_{k=1}^{p^n} \binom{p^n}{k}X^k$, and ${\rm ord}_p\binom{p^n}{k} = n - {\rm ord}_p(k) \geq n - k$, so for $1 \leq k \leq n$ we have $\binom{p^n}{k}X^k \in (p^{n-k}X^k)$ and for $k > n$ we have $\binom{p^n}{k}X^k \in (X^n)$. Thus $(1+X)^{p^n} - 1$ tends to $0$ in the $(p,X)$-adic topology on $O[[X]]$, so 
$\varprojlim O[[X]]/((1+X)^{p^n}-1) \cong O[[X]]$ for the same reason $\varprojlim \mathbf Z_p/(p^{n_i}) \cong \mathbf Z_p$ for any increasing sequence $n_i$. (Note: $O[[X]]$ is complete for the $X$-adic topology, but $(1+X)^{p^n} - 1$ does *not* tend to $0$ in the $X$-adic topology. This sequence does not tend to $0$ in the $p$-adic topology either, but also $O[[X]]$ is not $p$-adically complete.)

Comment: I meant $p$-adically complete: $O \cong \varprojlim O/(p^n)$. I do not want to say $P$-adically complete when $O$ is the integers of $\mathbf C_p$ since that $P$ does not have its powers shrink to $0$: $P^k = P$ for all $k \geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted my questions thinking I was in another thread. Sorry.